# Union type cannot resolve Object Type at Runtime

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, starlette, graphql-python

I am setting up a GraphQL Server with Python using Starlette and Graphene and ran into a problem I cannot find a solution for. The [Graphene Documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/unions/) does not go into detail regarding the union type, which I am trying to implement.
I set up a minimum example based on the graphene documentation which you can run to replicate this problem

```
import os

import uvicorn
from graphene import ObjectType, Field, List, String, Int, Union
from graphene import Schema
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.graphql import GraphQLApp
from starlette.routing import Route

mock_data = {
    "episode": 3,
    "characters": [
        {
            "type": "Droid",
            "name": "R2-D2",
            "primaryFunction": "Astromech"
        },
        {
            "type": "Human",
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "homePlanet": "Tatooine"
        },
        {
            "type": "Starship",
            "name": "Millennium Falcon",
            "length": 35
        }
    ]
}


class Human(ObjectType):
    name = String()
    homePlanet = String()


class Droid(ObjectType):
    name = String()
    primary_function = String()


class Starship(ObjectType):
    name = String()
    length = Int()


class Characters(Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (Human, Droid, Starship)


class SearchResult(ObjectType):
    characters = List(Characters)
    episode = Int()


class RootQuery(ObjectType):
    result = Field(SearchResult)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_result(_, info):
        return mock_data


graphql_app = GraphQLApp(schema=Schema(query=RootQuery))

routes = [
    Route("/graphql", graphql_app),
]

api = Starlette(routes=routes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(api, host="127.0.0.1", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

If you then go to **http://localhost:8080/graphq** and enter the following query

```
query Humans{
  result {
    episode
    characters {
      ... on Human {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error

```
 {
    "data": {
        "result": {
            "episode": 3,
            "characters": null
        }
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Abstract type Characters must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field SearchResult.characters with value \"[{'type': 'Droid', 'name': 'R2-D2', 'primaryFunction': 'Astromech'}, {'type': 'Human', 'name': 'Luke Skywalker', 'homePlanet': 'Tatooine'}, {'type': 'Starship', 'name': 'Millennium Falcon', 'length': 35}]\", received \"None\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 4,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

which I am now stuck with. Maybe someone has done this already and can help out? **How can I resolve this at runtime**. I have already tried different approaches for example I changed classes **Character** and **RootQuery**:

```
class Character(Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (Human, Droid, Starship)

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data
        self.type = data.get("type")

    def resolve_type(self, info):
        if self.type == "Human":
            return Human
        if self.type == "Droid":
            return Droid
        if self.type == "Starship":
            return Starship


class RootQuery(ObjectType):
    result = Field(SearchResult)
    
    @staticmethod
    def resolve_result(_, info):
        return {**mock_data, "characters": [Character(character) for character in mock_data.get('characters')]}
```

resulting in

```
{
    "data": {
        "result": {
            "episode": 3,
            "characters": [
                {},
                {
                    "name": null
                },
                {}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

jkimbo answered the question [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/1244):

```
class Character(Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (Human, Droid, Starship)

    @classmethod
    def resolve_type(cls, instance, info):
        if instance["type"] == "Human":
            return Human
        if instance["type"] == "Droid":
            return Droid
        if instance["type"] == "Starship":
            return Starship


class RootQuery(ObjectType):
    result = Field(SearchResult)

    def resolve_result(_, info):
        return mock_data
```

Note I'm just returning mock_data and I've updated the resolve_type method to switch based on the data. The Union type uses the same resolve_type method as Interface to figure out what type to resolve to at runtime: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/interfaces/#resolving-data-objects-to-types